# .htaccess guide / examples / tutorials?

Tags: htaccess, url-rewriting, guide

Does anyone know of any good guides for someone new to editing and making .htaccess files. Anything about rewriting urls, directory access and passwording a directory would be great.

Comment: Did you try Google yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Here's the wiki of [serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com/questions/214512/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-mod-rewrite-rules-but-were-afraid-to-as)
- The [howto's htaccess official guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html)
- The [official mod_rewrite guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

### Two hints to help you doing the job faster:

---

Please try to use the `RewriteLog` directive: it helps you to track down problems:

```
# Trace:
# (!) file gets big quickly, remove in prod environments:
RewriteLog "/web/logs/mywebsite.rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 9
RewriteEngine On
```

---

My favorite tool to check for regexp:

http://www.quanetic.com/Regex (don't forget to choose ereg(POSIX) instead of preg(PCRE)!)

You use this tool when you want to check the URL and see if they're valid or not.

Answer (score 1):

How about [the official documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/) ? Next to that, [this guide](http://www.htaccess-guide.com/) may be a good introduction.